# how to check all available characters in a font file?

Tags: linux, truetype-fonts, fontconfig

I have some truetype fonts which support UTF-8 characters. I can use "fc-list" to find certain font. How can I check all available characters in some font? Such as how many characters supported in "AR PL New Sung ExtB".

Comment: In the newer fontconfig, there is a `fc-query` program which can list the Unicode ranges that the font covers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a different commandline tool, `ttfdump`, assuming you're looking at a TTF font file. It should also work for OTF fonts, if they belong to the TTF variety:

```
ttfdump /path/to/your/file.ttf  \
   | grep -E '(Number of Glyphs:|numGlyphs:|numberOfHMetrics:)'
```

This should get you the number of glyphs. You'll possibly see up to four different numbers, if the TTF is in some way b0rken. Sane TTF will return identical numbers for all three entries, in which case you may be pretty confident that you got the correct number:

```
ttfdump /Library/Fonts/WeidemannStd-Book.otf  \
  | grep -E '(Number of Glyphs:|numGlyphs:|numberOfHMetrics:)'

    numberOfHMetrics:      253
    numGlyphs:             253
```

Another example:

```
ttfdump /Library/Fonts/DroidSerif-Regular.ttf \
   | grep -E '(Number of Glyphs:|numGlyphs:|numberOfHMetrics:)'

     numberOfHMetrics:     609
     numGlyphs:            609
     numGlyphs:            609
     Number of Glyphs:     609
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new (command line) method to determine the number of glyphs contained in a (TTF or OTF) font which I became aware of recently.

Use the ***`luaotfload-tool`*** which ships with the ***`luaotfload`*** package for LaTeX.

Run, for example:

```
 luaotfload-tool --find="fira mono" -I | grep glyphs
    number of glyphs: 1485
```

If you skip the `| grep glyphs` part and replace it by `| less`, you'll get a lot more info about the font's metadata, which is also interesting in itself, like copyright + license info, font creator name and built-in font features.

The tool can also find an installed font for you, based on its name:

```
 luaotfload-tool --find="fira mono"
  luaotfload | resolve : Font "fira mono" found!
  luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/Users/kp/Library/Fonts/FiraMono-Regular.otf"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: gucharmap]

gucharmap is a super convenient option. It can display all the characters, grouping them by Unicode blocks or scripts, and it lets copy them in the clipboard.

It can be installed using your package manager. It's part of Gnome, but can be installed separately. Its homepage is at https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gucharmap

Comment: gucharmap is available in MacOS with "brew install gucharmap"